# HP P6000 boot order not saving

Tags: boot, bios

It is Windows 7 on an HP P6000, and the problem is that the boot order does not persist across reboots. E.g.: I go into the BIOS and set to boot from hard drive, then CD/DVD drive, and it defaults the third and fourth to PXE and floppy respectively. I cannot remove or disable those, it has no option to do so that I've found.

After I save and quit, it boots normally into Windows. However, upon the next reboot it first tries PXE boot, then when that fails I am presented with a black screen saying:

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
```

Update:

I replaced the battery but that did not fix the problem. I cannot get the settings to save in the BIOS so that it boots from the HDD first every time.

Comment: Another thought: is or was the computer an office computer?  PXE is used in an office setting to "pre-boot" from a network before the operating system loads.  It enables the IT folks to maintain the computer remotely.  If you are using a PXE-configured computer at home, the boot failure is probably because it isn't finding the office network.  There may be another setting somewhere that forces PXE when you reboot.  If you are trying to change settings while connected to the office network, it is probably reloading default settings.  I'm not familiar enough with PXE to tell you where to look.

Comment: BTW, if you do figure out a way to permanently lower the PXE boot priority, it is a good idea to make the CD/DVD drive the first boot device.  If there is no disk installed, it will boot from the hard disk (second boot device).  This provides a mechanism to boot from something other than the hard disk if it fails, or you need to run a recovery disk, or you want to run a Linux liveDVD, etc.

Comment: No, it's a neighbor's home desktop. It has never been a part of a office network as far as I know of.

Comment: I did a quick check online to see if this was a common problem with this model.  Curiously, I came across almost the same experience a year ago: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1824500/boots-exit-bios-setup.html.  Maybe someone else who is more of a BIOS expert will have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is the CMOS battery (typically a button battery on the motherboard).  They usually last 3-5 years, although their life can be shorter if the motherboards or computers were stored in a hot location before you bought the system.  Check the expiration date on the replacement battery.  It should still have at least 5 years on it.

Comment: There is no expiration date on the battery, it just says the manufacturer, voltage rating, and model.

Comment: Are you referring to the original battery or the replacement?  The expiration date is typically on the retail packaging, not the battery, itself.  You can check the voltage on the original battery if you have a voltmeter or a battery checker designed to test button cells (a regular tester may drain a button battery).  They are usually 3 volt batteries, which are actually higher than that when fresh.  If you use a voltmeter and it measures less than 2.7 volts with no load, it is weak.  Less than about 2.5 volts should be replaced.

Comment: If you don't have a meter or tester, it's cheap to just replace the battery and see if that fixes the problem.  If the computer was purchased new more than a few years ago, add 6 months or a year to that for the battery age (more if the motherboard or computer was ever warehoused in a hot area), and you are likely at the life expectancy of the original battery.

Comment: It probably is the battery, which is the original one that came with the computer. I don't have the voltmeter, so I'll just go pick up a replacement. Thank you. I'll mark your response as the answer if that fixes it.

Comment: It was not the battery, I think I may have found where the problem lies but I'm not sure what is causing it.